# How can I join two SQL tables, putting a value from the 2nd table into a column in the 1st?

Tags: sql

I've no idea where to start with this! I have two tables, one which shows a company mobile phone bill in detail, like this:

[image]

And another table which shows line rental, like this:

[image]

I want to "merge" the two tables, so that the Line Rental value is shown in the Call Cost column, the value "Line Rental" is shown in the Call Class column, and the Bill Date is shown in the Date column:

[image]

Comment: Use the UNION ALL operator for the two queries on each table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
select User,callcost,callclass,date from 1sttable
union all
select User,LineRental,'Line Rental',billdate from 2ndtable
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`

Comment: In 2nd table, column User seems different always ... don't think there is reason for UNION ALL

Comment: @Veljko89 There is, union does unnecessary  testing for dups, union all will be faster

Comment: Union all is always quicker